# How to properly load more items in a recyclerView, using Retrofit ? (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm really new to Android Dev, and I'm actually working on a personnal project in Kotlin, using retrofit to do the API calls.

I've implemented `infiniteScroll` on the app, but the problem here is that when I hit the bottom of the page, my item gets replaced by the new items.

I don't want that behavior, I would prefer that every items just stack one another without loosing the previous items.

here in my fragment, is the function that I call to repopulate my view:

```
    private fun getPopularMovies(page: Int){
        val repository = MoviesRepositoryProvider.provideMovieRepository()
        repository.getPopularMovies(page)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe ({ result ->
                moviesAdapter = MovieAdapter(movies = result.results)
                moviesList.adapter = moviesAdapter
            }, { error ->
                error.printStackTrace()
            })
    }
```

Comment: look at android paging library it has awesome features https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: [3 RecyclerView load more Examples - Retrofit too..](https://androidride.com/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scroll-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@veritas1 was right
but to properly correct my mistake I had to do so :

All of this is in my Fragment.

First declaring the adapter, and the array that will contain my informations:

```
    private var moviesAdapter: MovieAdapter? = null
    private var movies = ArrayList<Movie>()
```

and in the callback, take the previous request and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

```
    movies.addAll(result.results)
    moviesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Since I'm using recyclerView I had to properly set my Adapter

```
    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        moviesList.apply {layoutManager = layoutMng}
        moviesList.adapter = moviesAdapter
        moviesList.addOnScrollListener(
            InfiniteScrollListener({getPopularMovies(page)},{nextPage()}, layoutMng))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Paging library:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
.subscribe ({ result ->
   moviesAdapter = MovieAdapter(movies = result.results)
   moviesList.adapter = moviesAdapter
}
```

You are creating a new adapter for each api response. You want to set your adapter once. Then you can pass results to the same adapter on each response, and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Something like:

```
// Initial adapter set
moviesAdapter = MovieAdapter()
moviesList.adapter = moviesAdapter

// Then on callback
.subscribe ({ result ->
   moviesList.addResults(result.results)
}
```

Then inside the adapter, add the new results to your list, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I think that will do the trick, I knew it was something like that but since i'm really new to these I just cannot figure how to set it, It won't happen again :D
I'll tell you if it works

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors, I've tried to get rid of them but, I think you'll be more efficient than me x) ! 
When I try to add these variables directly inside the fragment I get Unsolved Reference error : 
```
    private var moviesAdapter = MovieAdapter(movies = result.results)
    private var moviesList.adapter = moviesAdapter
```
And in the callback, addResult is also an unsolved reference

For the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() I don't know exactly where to put it ... 

Thank you kindly !

Comment: For MovieAdapter, init with empty constructor as you don't have reference to results yet, `private var moviesAdapter = MovieAdapter()`.
`moviesList` must reference the recyclerview first e.g using findViewById, it must be in your code somewhere, you didn't post that part.
`addResults` is a method that you need to define....